# VideoView - ship video files with app

Tags: android, video

I want to play a mp4 file in an Activity using the `VideoView`. But I want to somehow have the mp4 saved in my app itself, just like images can be saved under R.drawable. So, the video ships with the app. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store them in `res/raw/` and access with `openRawResource()`, from [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode) (emphasis is mine):

> Access to Original Files
>
> While uncommon, you might need access your original files and directories. If you do, then saving your files in res/ won't work for you, because the only way to read a resource from res/ is with the resource ID. Instead, you can save your resources in the assets/ directory.
>
> Files saved in the assets/ directory are not given a resource ID, so you can't reference them through the R class or from XML resources. Instead, you can query files in the assets/ directory like a normal file system and read raw data using AssetManager.
>
> **However, if all you require is the ability to read raw data (such as a video or audio file), then save the file in the res/raw/ directory and read a stream of bytes using [openRawResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)).**